# Using ui:inputCheckbox with LDS not showing value

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Using `ui:inputCheckbox` with LDS for a new contact is giving me error if I don't select checkbox.

If I select the checkbox and then unselect it, it works, else it is giving an error

> INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD
>
> value not of required type

---

`<ui:inputCheckbox value="{!v.object.selected__c}" />`

What am I missing? If I want to pass `false` to the field, I have to select and then unselect it.

## Edit

from the comments:
I had tried `lightning:input` typed `checkbox` as well, but I faced setting it value properly; that's why I went for `ui:inputCheckbox`.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using base lightning components from the lightning namespace?

Comment: Which component do you suggest?

Comment: Which tag are you using? lightning:recordForm or force:recordData?

Comment: LDS is `force:recordData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended option for UI components is to use a base Lightning component.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleInputCheckbox

They eventually supersede any component from the `ui` namespace.